# Bare minimum javascript files required for an ASP.NET MVC 4 project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Which javascript files are required for a basic ASP.NET MVC 4 project that needs to avail the following features:

a) Client side validation (I'd assume the files in the bundles `~/bundles/jqueryval` for unobtrusive javascript and unobtrusive javascript validation and the basic `jquery-1.7.1.js` (or its minified version) from the bundle `~/bundles/jquery`)

b) Ajax calls and ASP.NET MVC 4's Remote Validation (I assume `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` or its minified version. Since there's no bundle registered for this file in the `BundleConfig.cs`, I assume I must add one if I need it and must also then `Styles.Render` that bundle in the layout or the view). Is this correct?

c) HTML 5 (Do I need `modernizr.js`?)

d) What is the file `knockout-2.1.0.js` for?

e) Will ASP.NET MVC automatically pick up the minified versions if I set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` in the `BundleConfig.cs` file?

Comment: You don't really need javascript to do stuff on the server in C#.

Comment: d) Knockout is a kind of MVVM script framework - http://knockoutjs.com/. It's for performing client side binding to javascript 'view models'. I've used it recently, it's ok for simple stuff.

Comment: Thanks, @adeneo. I know that.

Comment: @DylanMorley: What you say implies that a model also resides on the client. I take it you are referring to a situation where I pulled out some JSON onto the client and now I want to use that JSON as a model on the client side to do stuff to the view, i.e. the control, in the client.

Comment: Yeah - it's the idea that instead of just having lots of jquery handlers attaching to various elements and performing manipulations, you create a structured ViewModel on the client, in javascript, that represents your view. You can then use knockout bindings to create 2 way binding against HTML\javascript. You can have MVC return a model that you convert to a JSON object and use in knockout, or your can create your own just to perform the client side interactions. Checkout the site in my last comment, there are some good examples.